# MongoDB upsert - know version of the data before the update, in case of update

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, with the write concern enabled, I can get the information if the DB executed an update or insert. Is it possible to know, in case of an update, what was the data before the update? Something like an update trigger in a traditional RDBMS - deleted and inserted.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) to update and return the document state before the modification.

Comment: Thank you, looked at this before but somehow I've missed the fact it allows `upsert`s too.